# How do i upload large size file on fineuploader

Tags: php, large-files, fine-uploader

I am using the fineuploader plugin for upload files, but i can't upload large size file (about 2 GB), i had done the following things to do this upload

1. Changed php.ini following

   ```
   memory_limit,
   upload_max_filesize,
   post_max_size
   ```
2. `$uploader->sizeLimit = null;` on `endpoint.php`

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you have to configure your server:

php.ini:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = "your_tmp_folder"
max_file_uploads = ? ;( value should be >= 1)
upload_max_filesize = ? ;(Maybe, in your case, you should enable 2048M or more)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

After making these changes, you may need to restart Apache.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

If the **upload_max_filesize** is larger than **post_max_size**, you must increase **post_max_size** so that it is bigger than **upload_max_size**.

If the value of **post_max_size** is larger than **memory_limit**, you must increase **memory_limit** so that it is larger than **post_max_size**.